# Swap x and y axis in a LineSeries chart (DataVisualization.Charting)

Tags: .net, silverlight, wpftoolkit, datavisualization.toolkit

I want to make the y axis the independent axis, i.e. turning the horizontal rendering of a line series into a vertical one. This is the code that I started with:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <charting:Chart>
      <charting:Chart.Axes>
        <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="True" Name="xAxis" />
        <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True" Name="yAxis" />
      </charting:Chart.Axes>

      <charting:LineSeries
          Name="lineSeries"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          IndependentValuePath="Indep"
          DependentValuePath="Dep">
      </charting:LineSeries>
    </charting:Chart>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

First I tried adding

```
<charting:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
    <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" />
</charting:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>

<charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
    <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="X" />
</charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
```

This results in a `System.InvalidOperationException` with a message saying

> Assigned independent axis cannot be used. This may be due to an unset Orientation property for the axis.

However, when swapping the values of `"X"` and `"Y"` in the above snippet, there's no exception and everything works fine, except of course that the axes aren't oriented the way I want them.

Next thing I tried is doing it programmatically:

```
lineSeries.IndependentAxis = yAxis;
lineSeries.DependentRangeAxis = xAxis;
```

which gives me the same exception. Again, when swapping `xAxis` and `yAxis` in the statements above, there's no exception.

Any idea how to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Not making any progress on the axis swapping front, I tried the **generic WPF way of rotating controls**. It's as easy as adding the following under the `<charting:Chart>` element and it works:

```
<charting:Chart.LayoutTransform>
  <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="90"/>
</charting:Chart.LayoutTransform>
```

Except that if you really only want to swap the dependent/independent axes, `RotateTransform` is akin to the sledgehammer. Because then you have to adapt the locations of the axes and also rotate them -90 degrees. However, this is all doable and lacking a more straightforward solution I decided to go with this.